# How do i set caches expiration time through javascript using service worker or cache object

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, service-worker, cache-control

I am able to delete cache data using delete method.
But i want to automatically delete cache data using expiration time. example it should get deleted in 6 hours.

```
caches.delete(cacheName).then(function(boolean) {
  // your cache is now deleted
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before sending a cached file to client, You can check when file have been fetch and if it's too old, fetch a new one :

```
const url = request.url;
caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
  cache.match(url).then(response => {
    if(!response) {
      return fetch(url);
    }

    const date = new Date(response.headers.get('date'))
    // if cached file is older than 6 hours
    if(Date.now() > date.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6){
      return fetch(url);
    }

    // else return cached version
    return response;
  })
})
```

Comment: This is a good starter solution. And I think this will work in some common cases, but like anything the real world is in the long tail.
I wont go into the details here, limited space, but the best way to invalidate cache by a time requires setting rules for different route patterns. The easiest way to do this is leveraging IndexedDB. I have done some complicated code for this. But I recommend checking out Workbox which surfaces invalidation by time and # of responses as a plugin to the different caching patterns

Answer (score 1):

We don't have an inbuilt method in the cache object to delete the cache after some time but we can use the setTimeout() method which is used to executes a function, once, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds. So, by setting the time you can call this delete method and flush the data.

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

The above is the google doc for the cache. Hope this will help you.

Comment: hi, @gajendran thanks for your help. But I could not find setTimeout() method in the doc, also I searched for my solution to set an expiration time for cache using javascript but did not get it.